# In kafka 0.8 API, what is the replicaId value supposed to be when creating an OffsetRequest?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am converting an application to Kafka 0.8 from Kafka 0.7, and I am having to make use of the new API's for a simple consumer. In doing so I was following along with the examples [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+SimpleConsumer+Example) and converting to the API from our current implementation. However when creating an OffsetRequest object the example passes a string as the third argument, the jar that I have pulled from the apache kafka expects an arg of type string called "replicaid" I cannot find any documentation on what this is value is, can someone explain what it is and if there are defaults for this like there are on other similar kafka API's I would appreciate knowing what they are.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not jar that you pulled -- you're using somewhat internal api (`kafka.api.OffsetRequest`), instead of the one that is shown in example (`kafka.javaapi.OffsetRequest`).

If you still want to use the former one, set `replicaid` to [default value](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8.1/core/src/main/scala/kafka/javaapi/OffsetRequest.scala#L39): `kafka.api.Request.OrdinaryConsumerId` (which is -1 actually), but I advise you to fall back to `kafka.javaapi.OffsetRequest`.